# Count Unique Items in Text File Using Perl

Tags: perl, unique

I have a text file with thousands of names listed First Name | Last Name.  Any examples on how to use Perl to count only the unique last names?

I am already doing a standard count using $count++ to get the grand total, but I still need to know a unique count.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

The standard approach is to use a hash (associative array) whose keys are the strings you want to count. Since a hash only includes a given key at most once, this lets you count distinct strings. For example:

```
my @input_list = ('a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a');
my %result_hash;
foreach my $val (@input_list) {
    ++$result_hash{$val};
}
# %result_hash is now (a => 3, b => 2)
print scalar keys %result_hash; # prints '2' (the number of keys)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I have tried the code, but when the keys print, it is just a series of 1's, and it is counting each item and not just unique ones.  Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

    'code' my @input_list = (@fieldsagain[1]);
     my %result_hash;
    foreach my $val (@input_list) {
    ++$result_hash{$val};
}
# %result_hash is now (a => 3, b => 2)
print scalar keys %result_hash; # prints '2' (the number of keys)'code'

Comment: @user1681502: It sounds like you are running this code once per loop iteration, and are simply counting the number of distinct values *in each line*. Since each line contains one distinct value, that will obviously give you a whole lot of `1`. So, let's take a step back. Do you understand the example that I posted? If yes, then you should be able to apply its logic to your own case. If no, then please indicate what you do not understand.

Comment: Thank you.  I actually have it within an if statement because the report opens the file and pulls a list of names entered between a date range, and I just need it to count unique.  When I print the array to the screen, I can see all of the names.  So, I'm not sure what I'm missing.  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @user1681502: I'm not sure what you're missing, either. In your previous comment, you had `@input_list = (@fieldsagain[1])` followed by code to count the distinct elements of `@input_list`. Since `(@fieldsagain[1])` is a single-element list, that count will naturally be `1`.

Comment: If I don't include the [1], how will it know which field to count by?  I tried using just @fieldsagain, and it counted each line.

Comment: @user1681502: I'm not saying you shouldn't include the `[1]`, I'm saying that `(@fieldsagain[1])` is a single-element list, and so the code that you've posted cannot possibly be doing what you want. (I'm not telling you how to fix your program, because I can't see your program. All I can tell you is what's wrong with the code-snippet you posted.)

Answer (score 1):

Because keys of a hash are always unique, I suggest that you can make elements, which should be unique in a set, the keys of a hash.
In your case, using a hash that have last names as keys to remove repetitive ones and to count the number of people that have each last name.

```
$nameList=['Eric|Johnson',
            'Herbert|Schildt',
            'Carl|Schildt',
            'Rose|Johnson',
            'Allen|Johnson',];
$nameHash={};
map {$_=~/\|(\w+)/; $nameHash->{$1}+=1;} @{$nameList};
# read the string behind "|"
# subsequently, make this string the key of hash
# increase the value of this key to count the number of people having this last name
map {print "$_: $nameHash->{$_} people\n"} keys %{$nameHash};
```

Then, you can get the result like

```
Johnson: 3 people
Schildt: 2 people
```

All in all, recall hash anytime you want a set. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it, hopefully a bit more readable:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %names = ();
while (  my $name = <DATA>)
{
     chomp($name);
     my ($fname, $lname) = split(/\|/, $name);
     if (exists($names{$lname}))
     {
       $names{$lname} += 1;
     }
     else
     {
       $names{$lname} = 1;
     }

}

foreach my $name (sort { $names{$b} <=> $names{$a} } keys %names) {
  printf "%s: %s\n", $name, $names{$name};
}

print "Unique Names: " . scalar keys(%names) . "\n";

__DATA__
Rosetta|Drayer
Celinda|Blaylock
Twana|Riner
Mike|Riner
Bob|Riner
Linda|Riner
Liliana|Littlejohn
John|Littlejohn
Candance|Candanoza
Brian|Candanoza
George|Candanoza
Noreen|Frandsen
Nakisha|Feltmann
Vanetta|Feltmann
Lorretta|Feltmann
Domenic|Feltmann
Madalene|Feltmann
Rosalinda|Feltmann
Brandie|Feltmann
Nu|Feltmann
Tennille|Feltmann
```

**Output** - sorted by number descending order

```
Feltmann: 9
Riner: 4
Candanoza: 3
Littlejohn: 2
Frandsen: 1
Drayer: 1
Blaylock: 1

Unique Names: 7
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to respond.  I think maybe I haven't ask the question correctly.  What I'm actually looking for is a total count of unique names.  So, in your example, it would be 7 because there are seven unique names.  Can you tell me how to tweak your example to get that?  Could I just use a count in the foreach loop?  Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem. Just add this to the end: print "Unique Names: " . scalar keys(%names) . "\n";

Comment: Output: Unique Names: 7

Comment: Thank you.  I'm already opening and reading the text file.  The last name is in @fieldsagain[1].  I tried using 
while (  my $name = @fieldsagain[1]), and I just got the 1's again.  If I use while (  my $name = @fieldsagain), I just get a total line count.

Comment: Ok looks like @fieldsagain is an array containing the first and last name, then please try: $fieldsagain[1] instead of @fieldsagain[1].

Comment: It would've been easier to fit an answer around the code you already have if you'd included it (or at least the relevant parts) in the question

Answer (score 1):

This is another way using the uniq function:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::MoreUtils 'uniq';


my @names = ();
while (  my $name = <DATA>)
{
     chomp($name);
     my ($fname, $lname) = split(/\|/, $name);
     push(@names, $lname);
}

my @uniq = uniq @names;
print "Unique Names: " . scalar @uniq . "\n";

__DATA__
Rosetta|Drayer
Celinda|Blaylock
Twana|Riner
Mike|Riner
Bob|Riner
Linda|Riner
Liliana|Littlejohn
John|Littlejohn
Candance|Candanoza
Brian|Candanoza
George|Candanoza
Noreen|Frandsen
Nakisha|Feltmann
Vanetta|Feltmann
Lorretta|Feltmann
Domenic|Feltmann
Madalene|Feltmann
Rosalinda|Feltmann
Brandie|Feltmann
Nu|Feltmann
Tennille|Feltmann
```

**Output**

```
Unique Names: 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a hash to keep track of the values, and then count at the end:

```
perl -lne '
     my ($ln) = (split /\s*\|\s*/)[1];
     $h{$ln}++;
     END { print scalar keys %h }
  ' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a dictionary. You would read the lines, one by one (in a while loop, probably), remove newline characters, split by the pipe character, so you have a variable, say `$lastname`, which has the field you want.

Then, you do the following: `$count{$lastname}++`.

Note that `$count{$lastname}` is completely unrelated to `$count`; it is a separate variable.

Once your loop is complete, you can go through each lastname: `foreach $lastname (keys(%count)) {...` and print out `$lastname` and `$count{$lastname}`.